# How to manage appleevents in Xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript, osx-leopard, appleevents

I want to add an applescript dictionary to my project, but I need to manage **AppleEvents** to create Methods, classes and events. How I can manage the **AppleEvent codes** in xcode.

#### Note:

I don't have the ***AppDelegate*** class in the project and I have **Mac OS X Leopard** and **XCode 3.2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible.
Now I'm using Xojo, that can do this.
Then, in the compiled app, I add an SDEF file and I set Scriptable property (in info.plist) to true.